# SQLite foreign key mismatch on insert Command

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

> 03-27 10:39:55.279 23303-23303/com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) foreign key mismatch - "Product" referencing
>   "Category" 03-27 10:39:55.280
>   23303-23303/com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement E/SQLiteDatabase:
>   Error inserting Code=2536 Price=5 CategoryID=1 Quantity=2 Name=Olá
>                                                                                            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch -
>   "Product" referencing "Category" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT
>   INTO PRODUCT(Code,Price,CategoryID,Quantity,Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:895)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:506)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Classes.DbAdapter.insertData(DbAdapter.java:131)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.example.danyalahmed.stockmanagement.Activities.Scan_Page$3.onClick(Scan_Page.java:162)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

if you check this,

```
Error inserting Code=2536 Price=5 CategoryID=1 Quantity=2 Name=Olá
```

you can see that I have the CategoryID = 1.

when i create the DB i put there the categories:

```
INSERT INTO Category VALUES(1, 'OTHERS');
INSERT INTO Category VALUES(2, 'Crisp');
INSERT INTO Category VALUES(3, 'Sweet');
```

here is the product structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (" +
      " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE," +
      "Name VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
      "Code VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
      "Quantity INTEGER NOT NULL," +
      "PRICE DOUBLE NOT NULL," +
      "CategoryID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
      "FOREIGN KEY(CategoryID) REFERENCES Category(ID));
```

and here is the query:

```
public boolean insertData(String Table, String[] Columns, String[] Values) {   
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    for (int i = 1; i < Columns.length; i++) {
        contentValues.put(Columns[i].replace(Table + ".", ""), Values[i].trim());
    }
    return ((db.insert(Table, null, contentValues)) != -1);
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the values are actually inserted int he database? Did you increase the database version to make the initialization run after adding the inserts?

Comment: What is the structure of Category table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that you did not read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) and forgot to make the `ID` column of the `Category` table the primary key.

Comment: ladies and gentlemen, place your bets :)

Comment: that was somewhere near, I made _id not ID